# Crafty, adding sprite's

Tags: html

I'm experimenting with HTML5 games and found 'Crafty' API to make HTML5 Games
I looked up the documentation but my sprite's won't show up.
The path to the spritesheet is correct and so are the coordinations, so i should miss something.

Anyone have an idea?

This is my code now, when i open the page i have a blue screen. (Crafty.background)

```
Crafty.scene('Scene1', function() {

    Crafty.background('rgb(150,215,255)');
    Crafty.sprite('img/sprites.png', 
    {introbanner: [0, 0, 100, 100]});

    var banner = Crafty.e('2D, DOM, introbanner');
    banner.x = 20;
    banner.y = 20;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are 3 things you can try:

1. Ensure your HTML is loaded from a web server.  Locally loaded files have security restrictions when loading in a browser.  If you see `file:` in your address bar, move your files onto a server and try again using `http:`
2. Try the full path to your image like so:
    Crafty.sprite('http://www.domain.com/img/sprites.png',
3. Open up the developer console and see if the image is even being requested by your browser.

Comment: That example URL does not work.  Can you try again or put it on JSFiddle.net?  Also, do you get any javascript errors?

Comment: Hey, sorry for the bad link, but took it down now anyway. found a fix!

Instead of '2D, DOM, introbanner' i used '2D, Canvas, introbanner'

Comment: Oh good to hear.  Could you upvote my answer/comments or mark them as helpful if they helped?